# Yii - Module with its own UserIdentity component

Tags: authentication, module, yii, php

I have started using Yii framework and I have a -newbie- question about the use of the **UserIdentity** component.

My application has a admin module, which will act as a backoffice for content showed into the real site. This module has its own table for admins `tbl_admin_user`.

I want to separate the login method (to check against that table instead of `tbl_user`) of the module from the one of the general site. For that, I have assumed that I need to implement the authenticate method of **UserIdentity** just for the module and not the full app, correct my if I'm wrong.

When I override that method, I get nothing. The admin module is using the **UserIdentity** located at the **protected\components** instead of its own.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must not import your module identification class.
To do so, simply modify your init function in your module class extending CWebModule as below :

```
public function init()
{
    $this->setImport(array(
        '#moduleName#.models.*',
        '#moduleName#.components.*',
    ));
}
```

Thus, all your module components (and models also) will be imported, i.e. your module identification class.

Take care : doing so, you have 2 imported classes with the same name **UserIdentity**.
If your application is well configured, the module one must take precedence while in the module because of the position of its directory in the include_path.
But you should give another name to your class extending **CUserIdentity** in your module, e.g. **AdminUserIdentity**. Then in your login action, you use **new AdminUserIdentity($username,$password)** instead of **new UserIdentity($username,$password)**. This will make your code cleaner.

Comment: can you give more explanation or example? english not my native language @_@

Answer (score 0):

in Yii2 I managed to override the User class by adding this to the admin module default controler:

```
    public function init() {
    // this overrides the User Identity class
    // and uses the one provided by the admin module
    \Yii::$app->set("user", [
         'class' => 'yii\web\User',
         'identityClass' => 'app\modules\admin\models\User',
         'enableAutoLogin' => true,
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In GiiModule we used:

```
/**
 * Initializes the gii module.
 */
public function init()
{
    parent::init();
    Yii::setPathOfAlias('gii',dirname(__FILE__));
    Yii::app()->setComponents(array(
        'errorHandler'=>array(
            'class'=>'CErrorHandler',
            'errorAction'=>$this->getId().'/default/error',
        ),
        'user'=>array(
            'class'=>'CWebUser',
            'stateKeyPrefix'=>'gii',
            'loginUrl'=>Yii::app()->createUrl($this->getId().'/default/login'),
        ),
        'widgetFactory' => array(
            'class'=>'CWidgetFactory',
            'widgets' => array()
        )
    ), false);
    $this->generatorPaths[]='gii.generators';
    $this->controllerMap=$this->findGenerators();
}
```

So if you want to change the login system for this module, just create another user for the module and you will decouple the user functionality from the app User functionality.